# Martingale representation theorem for almost adapted martingales

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, martingales

Given a filtration $\mathcal F_t$ on a probability space, we say a stochastic process $X$ is *almost* $\mathcal F_t$-*adapted* if there exists some $\mathcal F_t$-adapted process $Y$ such that $\underset{t \to \infty}{\lim} \mathbb \int_{t}^{\infty} \mathbb E[|X_s - Y_s|] ds = 0$.

Let $W_t$ be a standard Brownian motion, and $\mathcal F_t$ its augmented natural filtration.

Suppose $X$ is an almost $\mathcal F_t$-adapted process that is a martingale with respect to its natural filtration.

**Question:**

Does there exist an $\mathcal F_t$-predictable, $W$-integrable process $Z$ such that

$$\underset{M \to \infty}{\lim} \int_{M}^\infty \big[X_t - X_M - \int_{M}^{t} Z_s dW_s\big] dt = 0$$

almost surely?

Comment: In the "$\lim_t\int_{t}^{\infty}\mathsf{E}[|X_s-Y_s]\,ds=0$", do you assume that the processes $X,Y$ are
$(\Omega\times\boldsymbol{R}_+, \mathscr{F}\otimes \mathscr{B}(\boldsymbol{R}_+))$-measurable?

Comment: Ah, you can assume $Y$ is, but not $X$ of course.

Comment: If $X,Y$ are not measurable, how to define integral $dP\times ds$?

Comment: Oh, $\mathcal F \otimes \mathcal B(\mathbb R_+)$, not $\mathcal F_t \otimes \mathcal B(\mathbb R_+)$ progressively measurable. In that case yes.